_CHANGE_TYPE not working when streaming Google Big Query rows from Pub/Sub
The following link (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#change_data_capture) states that when streaming rows into Google Big Query from Pub/Sub, we should be able to set _CHANGE_TYPE = 'UPSERT' in the JSON in order to make sure the data is updated by Primary Key.
I currently have a primary key set and can write intial rows while testing, but when I try to rewrite the same row with the _CHANGE_TYPE value included, the message remains unack'd in the subscription.
I'm not able to find any relevant errors in logging.
Has anyone else had this issue or gotten this feature working?
Sample Schema:
id: STRING,
time: TIMESTAMP

Sample Pub/Sub Message 1:
{
  "id": "abcd1234",
  "time": "2024-09-01 00:00:00"
}

Sample Pub/Sub Message 1 (with UPSERT):
{
  "id": "abcd1234",
  "time": "2024-09-02 00:00:00",
  "_CHANGE_TYPE": "UPSERT"
}


My issue was the PubSub service account did not have enough permissions.
Depending on your use case you may have 3 entirely unique permissions scenarios, but to be sure I had this working for WRITE, UPSERT & DELETE I just gave my PubSub service account the BigQuery Admin permission. Probably overkill but works.

I tried the feature and it does work as expected, so there may be something specific to your use case. To understand why the message is not being processed, you should add a dead-letter topic to the subscription. You can attach a pull subscription to the dead-letter topic and look at the CloudPubSubDeadLetterSourceDeliveryErrorMessage attribute to understand why the message fails to get written to the BigQuery table.

I found the issue. It was due to lack of permissions. The permissions required to simply write data to the table are not sufficient to UPSERT and/or DELETE using CDC

How are you setting the _CHANGE_TYPE to upsert?
because if you send the row with the field included, it will not work, _CHANGE_TYPE is a pseudo column in BQ

It does work when you add it to the JSON payload for a pub/sub subscription that exports to big query.

@Camilo Jorquera How is it supposed to be sent when not using Pub/Sub?
